# How to disable Android AAPT Filter

Tags: android, cordova

I am running Android cordova project and the asset folder contains different files. After building i got this error:

```
(skipping file '.buildignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
(skipping file '.htaccess' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
```